# Private constants in JavaScript `class` syntax

Tags: javascript, constants, es6-class, private-members

I know I can create a private constant by putting it into an IIFE's closure:

```js
let testObj = (function() {
  const myConst = 'test value';

  return {
    showPrivateConst() { 
      return myConst;
    }
  }
})();

console.log(testObj.showPrivateConst()); // test value
```

But I'm looking for the best way to do this using `class` syntax and the `#` private indicator. So far, the best I've come up with is this:

```
class Test {
  get #myConst() {
    return 'test value';
  }

  showPrivateConst() {
    return this.#myConst;
  }
}

let testObj = new Test();
console.log(testObj.showPrivateConst()); // test value
```

This seems kind of baroque. Is this the way to do it, setting up a read-only private property to get a private constant, or is there a more idiomatic way to do it?

*Edit:* I've been getting some feedback about static properties being the way to do this. I've looked at static properties as well, and they pretty much give me the same question. I can't make a private static variable a constant, so it looks like I have to make it a readonly property using a getter method. Here's the example using a static property:

```
class Test {
  static get #myConst() {
    return 'test value';
  }

  showPrivateConst() {
    return Test.#myConst;
  }
}

let test = new Test();
console.log(test.showPrivateConst()); // test value
```

So, this gives rise to pretty much the same question. It seems kind of baroque, and I'm wondering if there's a more idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: Javascript doesn't really have class constants, never mind private ones. The usual thing would be a naming convention like `#MY_CONSTANT` to *signal* that it shouldn't be modified, or to use TypeScript with `readonly` and/or `static` modifiers to enforce that ever so slightly more vigorously.

Comment: But the getter is actually a good approach. You can’t redefine private identifiers as if they were general properties; e.g. you can’t do `Object.defineProperty(this, "#myConst", somethingElse);`.

Comment: Whoever closed this by linking it to a "duplicate" question about STATIC constants two minutes after I spent an hour writing it might want to look the question over more carefully, and perhaps get in the habit of looking questions over more carefully before closing them.

Comment: I think the question got closed not because of a misreading, but because of the assumption that the solutions will be the same. However, private properties are quite different from normal ones, and I can imagine that answers to this question will be very useful to future readers.

Comment: @deceze That "signaling" thing always has rubbed me the wrong way. :) I suppose it would make no difference to a constant whether it was static or an instance constant. Why would I need to use TypeScript to get a readonly constant, though? Seems I just did that in my example with POJ?

Comment: You seem to have missed my point: Javascript doesn't have *any* class constants, never mind *private* ones. Try to get regular class constants first (which you can only get with workarounds as you show), then worry about making them private…

Comment: *"That "signaling" thing always has rubbed me the wrong way."* — I get what you mean, but that's all you really want anyway. At runtime, pretty much everything is malleable anyway. You just want to signal to other developers that a constant shouldn't be modified. If the language can help you out there by explicitly raising errors, great, but in the end you just want developers to *not* write the name of a constant on the left hand side of an assignment expression. For which a naming convention should hopefully be sufficient for consenting adults.

Comment: *"Why would I need to use TypeScript to get a readonly constant"* — Because Javascript simply doesn't support that kind of thing out of the box, and Typescript adds those kind of additional sanity checks on top.

Comment: @deceze No, I don't think I've missed your point. I'm just responding that I don't really like either of the "usual" things you mention. (No offense intended, just don't like things to be loose, and don't like to use transpiled libraries if I don't have to.) The private readonly property seems to do the job, so my question is whether there's a more idiomatic way to do it. Seems to me that you are saying there isn't.

Comment: @deceze I wrote my last before reading yours. Good point you make about "all I really want anyway." I'm kind of holding onto the strongly typed language paradigms I started out with, I guess. JS has always seemed a bit loose to me, although the more I learn it the more I like it. And maybe TypeScript is something to look into. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yeah, Javascript *really* isn't strongly typed, so it's best to let go of that mindset. Typescript adds compile-time type checking and other sorts of sanity checks which you get in a strongly typed language back into Javascript, but Javascript itself will never be as strongly typed as, say, Java.

Comment: What you are asking for is very normal: this, on the "syntax" side. But on the OOP 'paradigm/whatever' side: ask yourself, why do you want a constant property in a class? So that it's the same value/unchangable throughout the instances. But doesn't that make the property a **class member** rather than an **instance member**? Memory wise, think about it: being a 'class member' it is only once in 'memory', no matter how many times you instantiate, rather than be multiple times for each instance you create...I come from a strongly-types background (C#), so I hope you get it...

Comment: As you edited, static private getter should be good.

Comment: @Ergis That's a good point. :)